# Google Experiment A/B hacking error on firefox

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, google-experiments

I'm trying to implement an A/B test using Google experiments. The site uses a PHP CMS without individual page files, so in the master page (Where the `<head>` is) I put a simple if statement to detect the page.

So instead of `<script> GOOGLE CODE </script>`

I have

`<script>if (document.URL=="http://www.mysite/"){ GOOGLE CODE }</script>`

This executes fine, but when the script chooses the variant page Firefox shows an error message saying "There has been a hacking attempt, Firefox is preventing this page from executing scripts". This only happens some of the time, most notably when the page loads through Google.

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

This actually turned out to be a server security setting. Apparently some servers poll triggering code for suspicious activity. If you're having a similar problem, try using a server-side language (PHP in my case) to do the same code rather than doing it with JS.